# Why does a graph take so much longer than a log?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Why does doing a "Revision Graph" take so much longer than doing a "Show Log"?

The Revision Graph starts at the head and counts down to Revision 1.  I'm up to over 1000 revisions and it takes about 1 minute to count down.

The Show Log is almost instant and only shows the revisions that this project has.  There are only about 10 revisions for this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The revision graph needs the information that a log on the repository root, from HEAD to r1 returns.

So: if you show the full log for the repository root you should get the same time.

See this [FAQ](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#revisiongraph) entry for an overview on how the graph works.

Comment: What kind of information?  I can't think of anything that the root would have that the sub-sub-sub-project needs.

Comment: I'll go with Stefan's answer - it's going to be more definitive than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the revision graph is not a built-in operation in the svn server, whereas the log is a built-in feature. To build the revision graph, TortoiseSVN has to generate many different queries against the server.